# How to declare variiables within functions in python function error code "name 'male' is not defined"

Tags: python, function, variables, scope, call

I want to write a program, that inputs height and gender, and based off of that it tells you what your ideal weight should be given your height and ideal BMI (22 for men, 21 for women).

However, when I call the function, it never works.

### Source Code

```
def BMI(h,g):
    h = int(input("your height \n"))
    g = str(input("input your gender, 'male' or 'female' \n"))
    male = "male"
    female = "female"
    if g == male:     
        w=22*((h)**2)
    if g == female:
        w=21*((h)**2)
    return(w)
```

### error code

```
"name 'male' is not defined"
```

Any help is appreciated
I am using python 3

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: why is the assignment of h and g inside the method. this should be outside the method

Comment: I'm voting to close this, because it's not reproductible and the only other issue is a minor typo (e.g. `BMI()`, not `BMI(h, g)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the function by @MrPrincerawat you can do that with:

```
def BMI(h,g):
    if g == "male":     
      w=22*((h)**2)
    elif g == "female":
      w=21*((h)**2)
    return(w)
```

call with:

```
BMI(100, 'male')
```

if you want to print:

```
print(BMI(100, 'male'))
```

if you want it as a variable:

```
weight = BMI(100, 'male')
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
def BMI():
    h = int(input("your height \n"))
    g = str(input("input your gender, 'male' or 'female' \n"))
    if g == "male":     
      w=22*((h)**2)
    elif g == "female":
      w=21*((h)**2)
    return(w)
```

Comment: I still get the error code, that "male" is not defined. Basically in the terminal i write:
BMI(1.83,male) 
and it just doesnt work. smh

Comment: as you are taking h and g as input inside function no need to do BMI(h,g)

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting can be only be explained if you're using Python 2. In this case, you must use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

```py
% python2
...
>>> input("input your gender, 'male' or 'female' \n")
input your gender, 'male' or 'female'
male
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'male' is not defined
>>> raw_input("input your gender, 'male' or 'female' \n")
input your gender, 'male' or 'female'
male
'male'
```

Comment: In the question is stating is using Python 3,

Comment: @FedericoBaù There's good evidence that's a false assumption!

Answer (score 0):

First, as [suggested by **Nacib Neme**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65363967/4541045), verify you are using Python 3 (Python 2 is still available, [though EoL](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) and may be the default `python` on many systems)

Next, you clobber the arguments to your function when you *always* set them inside it from `input`! Setting them outside of the function will have no affect on its output and always request data from the user. Either

- accept the input outside of your function and pass it as arguments
- set defaults (`None` is almost-always used to indicate optionality) and only override them if they were not set

  ```
  def fn(a=None, b=None):
      if a is None:
          # logic to set a
  ```

---

Here is an example of the first form in Python 3

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

def healthy_weight_from_bmi(height, gender=None):
    """ calculate a healthy body weight from height and gender, using a BMI constant
    """
    height = float(height)  # input could be a string, but should be a float
    try:  # select BMI constant based upon gender or choose average if missing
        healthy_bmi = {
            "m": 22.0,
            "f": 21.0,
        }[str(gender).lower()[0]]
    except Exception:  # ValueError, KeyError, IndexError..
        healthy_bmi = 21.5
    return round(healthy_bmi * (height**2))  # int


# collect height
height = input("enter height(meters) (q to quit): ")
if height.lower().startswith("q"):
    sys.exit("quit by user!")
try:
    height = float(height)
except ValueError:
    sys.exit("invalid height {}: expected a float".format(height))

# collect gender
gender = input("enter gender (optional): ")
if gender.lower().startswith("q"):
    sys.exit("quit by user!")

# calculate healthy weight from inputs
healthy_weight = healthy_weight_from_bmi(height, gender)
print("healthy weight: {}kg".format(healthy_weight))
```

Usage

```sh
% python3 ./bmi.py
enter height(meters) (q to quit): 1.7
enter gender (optional):
healthy weight: 62kg
```